# How to get dozens of thread to run simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, load-testing

We currently have a program which writes messages to a server. For volume testing, we run many instances of the same program, which is awkward. I'm working on a program which instead creates multiples threads for writing messages.

But, the problem is, the threads do not send messages at an even pace. Instead, some finish sending before others even start. Note that all the threads are started at about the same time, in a loop, and send the same messages.

Is there anything that can be done about this? What might be the cause of the problem?

Edit: I'm new, but I've been told that this isn't a problem when running separate instances of the program (as opposed to the multi-thread solution).

Comment: Sounds like you need something like [Gatling](https://gatling.io/). Otherwise: how is the number of threads related to your actual hardware?

Comment: How can we figure out the problem in code we can't see?

Comment: creates multiples threads ~= many instances of the same program.

Comment: @Ele Not for Java. It does make a difference whether you're starting 8 threads or 8 JVMs. JVM is big and heavy. JVM threads are more lightweight. Akka actors are way more lightweight.

Comment: Does your current method of creating a bunch of single thread programs _not_ have this "problem"? Problem in quotation marks because the way you describe it it doesn't sound like anything unusual is happening. You're not doing anything to ensure the threads start at the same time or to make them all progress at the same rate, so they don't.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I know that.  However, it's more efficient and cost-effective to execute the same program on different machines for horizontal scaling rather than vertical scaling.  Create a bunch of threads is not the right way to accomplish that kind of scenario.  Imagine a crash in your program, you will shut down the whole program? That's crazy and not suitable for production environment.

Comment: Akka actors maybe more lightweight, but do they give fairness in the face of bottlenecks?

Comment: @Ele - this is for load testing, not for a production environment.  As such, it just needs to work "well enough".  Gold plating a test tool is not a good investment of developer time.

Comment: @Cubic - is there a way to ensure they all start, process, and end at the same time?

Comment: @JackBeNimble - No there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything that can be done about this? What might be the cause of the problem?

Basically, the problem is that your system has bottlenecks:

- The number of cores that you have limits the number of threads that can actually run at a time<sup>1</sup>.
- The OS and networking limits the amount of network traffic that your system can send.
- The OS and disk hardware limits the amount of file I/O traffic your system can handle (if this is relevant here)
- Your multi-threaded application may have internal concurrently bottlenecks; e.g. threads waiting on mutexes to access shared data structures.
- There will also be the bottleneck which represents your server's ability to accept messages, especially under load.

(Some performance monitoring would give you some clues as to which of the above, or possibly others, was most important in your case.  In some cases you could address them ...)

In the face of bottlenecks, some of your Java threads will inevitably run slower than others.  There is nothing you can do about *that*.  It happens because the Java thread scheduler doesn't implement "fair" scheduling.  And more broadly, neither do the network and disk I/O systems.  (They are optimized for other things than fairness.)

But here's the (rhetorical) question for you.  Does it really matter that some threads take a longer time than others?  Isn't this equivalent to some real-life clients being slower than others (for some reason)?  What should matter to you is your server's behavior when faced with high load; i.e. the rate of requests it can sustain, and what happens when that rate is exceeded.

---

Now it is possible that your problem is that you have created vastly too meany threads.  (Some people are under the mistaken belief that N threads gives you N times speedup!)  Creating too many threads wastes resources<sup>2</sup>, and can lead to slower performance due to secondary effects.  If you have a huge number of tasks to perform, a better approach is to use an `ExecutorService` with a bounded thread pool.  Throw the tasks onto the queue, and let the service take care of thread creation, etc.

---

> I've been told that this isn't a problem when running separate instances of the program (as opposed to the multi-thread solution).

I think you have been "told" incorrectly.  If you launch N single-threaded applications simultaneously, you will most likely see *even more* variability in execution times.  (And throughput will be worse 'cos you now have the overhead of JVM warmup N times, instead of one time.)

---

<sup>1 - For example, if you have 8 physical cores or hyperthreads, that limits your application to 8 threads running at a time.  Any more is physically impossible.  If there are more than 8 threads that are runnable, some will be waiting to be scheduled.</sup>

<sup>2 - Each thread uses memory for its stack and for the objects that it references.  The increased memory footprint increases GC overheads, impacts on memory cache performance.  If you don't have enough *physical* memory, it can lead to excessive paging.</sup>

Comment: If you have 8 physical cores, there could only be 8 threads running simultaneously, but couldn't the JVM make it seem like they're all running at the same time?

Comment: 1) Whether it "could" or not, it doesn't.  2) How could it possibly do that efficiently; i.e. at native code speed?

Comment: Ok, I see. But, for example, if I launch 16 threads, does that mean 8 will finish before the next 8 start? Or will there be some switching between the first 8 and the second 8 before they're all done?

Comment: Nope.  You cannot draw any conclusions about which threads will finish first, or even the order in which they will start.  And at any point, one thread *could* be descheduled to give another thread a "turn".  Thread scheduling is *unspecified*.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.  Can you give me a reference which states that the amount of concurrent threads is limited to the physical cores? It makes sense, but I think I'm going to need to defend this position.

Comment: It follows from 1) knowledge of how hardware works and 2) JLS Chapter 17: *"While most of the discussion in the preceding chapters is concerned only with the behavior of code as executed a single statement or expression at a time, that is, by a single thread, the Java Virtual Machine can support many threads of execution at once. These threads independently execute code that operates on values and objects residing in a shared main memory. **Threads may be supported by having many hardware processors, by time-slicing a single hardware processor, or by time-slicing many hardware processors.**"*

Comment: Also, read Chapter 4 of "Operating System Concepts" by Silberschatz, Galvin & Gagne.  http://iips.icci.edu.iq/images/exam/Abraham-Silberschatz-Operating-System-Concepts---9th2012.12.pdf  Or any good OS Principles / Concepts textbook that talks about threads.

Comment: Ok, so, that helps. My boss seems to think that all the threads should be executing simultaneously - I just have no idea how to explain this.

Comment: Give HIM the textbook and chapter and get HIM to read it.  Seriously, this is all really common sense.  And he is ... I'm afraid ... just plain wrong.  (Tell him someone with a PhD in CS and 20+ years experience in Java said so.   If he would be influenced by that kind of specious argument.)